Stop Samsung-based ad popups
Please help me get rid of these ads on my Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra. I do not have Samsung Internet activated. I'm using Chrome. I have the best ad blocker, as well as antivirus, to no avail. These ads keep coming. It seems to happen when I click on anything on my screen, even my Email app.
Every ad seems to be different, and has nothing to do with anything I've previously searched. If I press and hold on the ad, it changes into a purple Saturn icon, with a white ring around it. I believe it belongs to Samsung Internet.
I have gone into settings and deleted all data and history. Anything saved has been deleted. All permissions have been blocked. I've reset the phone multiple times and gone into my applications and deleted just about every single thing I have.
Please, can anyone shed some light on this? I have called Samsung for help many times, but they seem to be more interested in hanging up on me.

Long shot, but one place that usually gets missed is a setting that allows the network to display ads.

Open Settings
Select Security and Privacy
Select Customisation Service
Turn Off Customised ads and direct marketing

